# iTunes is so laggy it's virtually unusable

Tags: windows-xp, itunes, performance

Are there any hacks for iTunes which make it less laggy? Something which replaces the UI with a more windows like one or something?

On my laptop (1.6 Ghz/1GB RAM) it's completely unusable.

Comment: What do you mean "Laggy"? Is it laggy when playing back music? videos?

Comment: Sorry, there is no help for ITunes in Windows!

Comment: 1.6 Ghz/1GB ram sounds like a netbook with an Atom processor.

Answer (score 3):

10 Tips To Make iTunes for Windows Run Faster
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/23480/10-tips-to-make-itunes-for-windows-run-faster/

Comment: I recently followed those suggestions and it made a noticeable difference on my netbook with an Atom processor.  I have a feeling a big part of that was turning off the access to the network media since we have about 5 computers and a Windows Home Server.

Answer (score 2):

The specs you provided sound a bit low. Have you tried shutting down all other apps to see if iTunes works at all on your machine?

The automatic analysis of all your mp3s for gapless playback and the search for covers may burn resources. Have a look at the status area and check if any of these one-shot background processes are running.

Here's a screenshot of the status area when iTunes is analyzing your music:

[image]

Comment: +1...iTunes is a notorious resource hog and is bloated to the extreme.  I'm surprised that machine isn't running for the hills yet.